# MATLAB: creating matrix with multiple diagonals using diag()

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to make a matrix that looks like this by using diag command from MATLAB.

```
    [0  0  7  0  2;
     0  0  0  3  0;
     0  0  0  0  1;
     0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0]
```

I figured how to do

```
    [0  0  7  0  0;
     0  0  0  3  0;
     0  0  0  0  1;
     0  0  0  0  0;
     0  0  0  0  0]
```

But can't seems to insert 2 at the first row/fifth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set multiple diagonals using a unique `diag()` call.
Knowing that Matlab will set every other entry as 0, you can do something like

```
A=diag([7 3 1],2)+diag(2,4);
```

in order to get

```
 0     0     7     0     2
 0     0     0     3     0
 0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

In other words you're creating two separate matrices with two `diag()` commands.
`diag([7 3 1],2)` will return

```
 0     0     7     0     0
 0     0     0     3     0
 0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

whereas `diag(2,4)` will return

```
 0     0     0     0     2
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

and finally, by summing these two matrices you'll get the final matrix.

Comment: @tk4982 Make sure to mark this answer as accpeted if it solved your ploblem.